# Managing child accounts in AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

We currently use AWS Organizations for creating child accounts and have over 100+ AWS accounts. So we don't have root credentials of these child accounts.

- Changing email distribution list of AWS accounts: We are going from plain old distribution list to "plus addressing based" approach, which will use dl of root account with a tag. Is there any process to automate this step without requiring root user login.
- Renaming the accounts: Over time the accounts are repurposed and it is better to rename the account to reflect new usage. Is there easy way to change name without logging as the root user?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the root credentials. If you have access to the emails that is setup with the child accounts you can regain access to the root user. Do so by use the forgot password link on the login page.

I have done so with accounts I have created with organization.